# Outer Apply in SQLAdapter

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, t-sql, adapter

Do I have to create a stored procedure to call to get this working? I am no friend of adapters in Visual Studio (The GUI-ones that gets destroyed instantly if you edit them :) ).

However I have this query that I got working (SQL Management Studio 2008 R2) with using Outer Apply (Similar to Left join). My VS-adapter does not accept this throwing "The OUTER APPLY SQL construct or statement is not supported". I therefore need help writing the code below in "Normal" t-sql :)

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.col1,t2.col2,t3.col2,t3.col4
FROM t1
OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 col1,col2,col3,col4
      FROM t2
      WHERE col3 = value
      AND t2.col1 = t1.col1
      ORDER BY col4 ASC
) AS  t3
```

Comment: Conditions "WHERE col3 = value" and 'ORDER BY col3 ASC' looks excessive for 'SELECT TOP 1'. Maybe another column condition was mented? Correct me, if Im wrong pls.

Comment: Doh!. Correct! Order By Should be col4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OUTER APPLY` is equivalent to a `LEFT JOIN`, will the following code fit your needs?

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.col1,t3.col2,t3.col4
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN 
 (
   SELECT TOP 1 col1,col2,col4
   FROM t2
   WHERE col3 = value
   ORDER BY col3 ASC
 ) t3
 ON t3.col1 = t1.col1
```

Comment: No it doesn't. This will only get me the first value in t2 and will only match t1 if I am extremely (un)lucky.

Comment: Do you have some test data and desired output then?

Comment: I ended up using a stored procedure, but if I will leave the question here if someone can shed some light on the issue.